# coordinate returned by xyCoordinate signal is different

Tags: qgis, api, c++, qgsmapcanvas

I am working on a project based on the api qgis 2.8 and qt 4.8.5
I have two computer one with the qgis 2.8.1 and the other with the  qgis 2.8.3
In my application I have a connect to the signal xyCoordinate to get the mouse position on the map

```
connect( this,  SIGNAL(xyCoordinates(QgsPoint)),
 this,  SLOT(displayCoord(QgsPoint))    );
```

I have two different result
on the 2.8.1 the coordinate returned is corresponding the latitude and longitude of the point
but on the 2.8.3 the coordinate is corresponding to nothing it look like double number

the code of my application is the same on both computer, same system ubuntu 14.04lts, qt4.8.5 libs, the same map

is there a difference between the qgis 2.8.1 c++ api and the qgis 2.8.3 ?